# How to change a variable before passing to curl?

Tags: php, curl

I have a question on this code.

```
$keyword = '';
$api_url = 'http://my-domain.com/';

// Init the CURL session
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );            
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );              
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(      
    'keyword'  => $keyword
) );
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

**Q1.** How can I output the value of 'keyword'?
**Q2.** If I detect the 'keyword' to be empty, I would like to give it a value before it's processed using curl. Is it possible?

Sorry, I'm not familiar with `curl` and hope to get enlightened here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think I'm not understanding your question correctly. Why is it specific to curl? Why couldn't you assign a value to that variable as you would in any other context?

Comment: `if (empty($keyword)) { $keyword = "default value"; }`

Comment: @Barmar Please don't post answers as comments, however short; it means they can't be voted on, or marked as accepted. If the question is worth answering, post an answer; if it's not, Vote To Close.

Comment: May be i didn't understand your question properly but here is the way, if variable keyword is empty you then assign a default value to it.    
     <?php         
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(      
            strong text'keyword'  => (!empty($keyword) ? $keyword : $defaultValue)
        ) );
    ?>

Answer (score -1):

First of all curl's postfields cannot be an array() if am not wrong:

So put your code as follows:

```
$keyword = !empty($keyword)?$keyword:'default value here';//if keyword is empty give it a value
$requestBody = json_encode(['keyword' => $keyword]);
$api_url = 'http://my-domain.com/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );            
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );              
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, requestBody);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

Comment: Passing an array will automatically format the request as form data (not JSON). From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php): "This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value."

Comment: i did not know that ... "if am not wrong" .... no need to down vote tho..

Comment: The downvote is because as well as being wrong, this doesn't actually answer the question, which was about how to set a default value for a variable. (Actually, it does, but hidden in a comment.)

Comment: not really hidden... okay okay... you are right..